# Copying and pasting into CKEditor from MS Word

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, ckeditor

I have a word document consisting of just two words "Hello to". This is actually a simplified version of the original document. The font-family for this text is Calibri (body). I don't notice any difference in formatting between these two words in the word document.

When attempting to copy and paste this text into ckeditor, the font-family of "Hello" is correctly preserved as Calibri, but the font-family of the word "to" in incorrectly changed to Arial. I don't understand why it doesn't also preserve the font-family of the "to" text.

Here is my config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {    
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = false;
};
```

Here is the source HTML in ckeditor upon pasting the text:

```
<p><span style="font-size:10pt"><span style="font-family:calibri">Hello </span>to</span></p>
```

The word document is available to download from the following link:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00848535251570855827

The above behaviour is evident using IE 11. Please can someone assist with this?

Comment: I assume you have explicitly set the font-family by highlighting the words in Word and setting the font-family to Calibri?

Comment: @robabby No it was from a pre-existing word document provided by our customer. If I create a new word document and set the font-family to Calibri by highlighting the words then the issue doesn't occur. The issue can also be resolved by using the clear all formatting function and then reapplying it  But I can't expect our customer to re-apply formatting on all their documents. Ideally I need to determine what is the issue with those specific word documents that prevent their content from being copy/pasted correctly into ckeditor.

Comment: We have similar customer issues come down the pipeline at my job where we use Word import for our CKEditor instances.  These are one-off circumstances and should be documented for the customer to know proper steps before import.  At least, that's how we will handle these.  If CKEditor is working as designed, and when text is properly formatted it works as designed, then there is little else you should have to do.  How many permutations should you be able to account for in code?

Comment: Some insight from CKEditor perspective - the HTML that MSWord generates when pasting into browser is absolutely terrible and often it happens that it's simply incorrect. I'm sure that CKEditor has some bugs too, but sometimes there's also not much it can do with a content that it's given. If you've got any doubts, you can report a ticket on http://dev.ckeditor.com and we'll check if there's a light in the tunnel.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I've submitted a ticket on the ckeditor site.

Comment: BTW. CKEditor 4.6 will come with a new paste-from-word implementation. There's a chance that many old bugs will be fixed. The code is now on review. See http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9991#comment:33 for more info.

Comment: @aw1975, You got the solution to keep the same format from word in the CKEditor? our client also expecting to keep the same format from word. kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, the below with some modification will do.

```
config.forcePasteAsPlainText = false;
config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = false;
config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;
config.allowedContent = true;
config.extraAllowedContent = 'p(mso*,Normal)';
config.pasteFilter = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would definitely work

```
CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText = false;
CKEDITOR.config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = false;
CKEDITOR.config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
CKEDITOR.config.extraAllowedContent = 'p(mso*,Normal)';
CKEDITOR.config.pasteFilter = null;
```

Thanks